# POST and process multiple check boxes PHP

Tags: javascript, php

I have a form with multiple checkboxes, the user can add multiple checkboxes as well so the amount can vary.

The check boxes sit within a div and I collect each checked box state as follows

[Javascript]

```
  $('#list input:checked').each(function(){
  checked = checked + "," + $(this).attr('id')
  })
```

I then post this to a php script that cleans it up.

[PHP]

```
  $checked = trim($checked, ','); 
  $checked = explode(",", checked);
```

then update a database ..

[SQL]

```
  foreach ($checked as &$id)
   {
  sql stuff .......
   }
```

This gets the required result, but I think there must be a better way?

Comment: better way from what perspective?

Comment: efficiently, a two step procedure at the moment. To me seems like there must be a better method

Answer (score 0):

For this part:

```
$('#list input:checked').each(function(){
  checked = checked + "," + $(this).attr('id')
})
```

You can do something like `serialize()` function.

Comment: Yes I did head down the `serialize()` path but it doesn't seem o work in chrome, theses checkboxes are not in a "form"

Answer (score 0):

You should have all the checkboxes of the same kind with the same name with brackets at the end like this: `x[]`, and they will have values instead of ids:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="x[]" value="1">
<input type="checkbox" name="x[]" value="2">
...
```

when you submit this form you'll get all the checked values in an array like this:

```
$_POST['x'] => array(1,2,3)
```

so you won't have to do any string manipulation. This is the proper way of submitting multi-select values in php.